# Entity Framework Composite Keys code first cause errors on model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, model, composite-key

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Entity Framework 4 code first approach and every time I try to specify composite keys using the key attribute on my models, I get this error:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : Number of Properties in
>   the Dependent and Principal Role in a relationship constraint must be
>   exactly identical.

I'm using the column attribute to differentiate ordering of the primary keys like so:

```
 public class Game
    {
        [Key, Column(Order=0)]
        public Guid GameId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Game()
        {
            this.GameId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if there is another approach to creating composite keys, or perhaps there is a way to stop getting this error? I know that it's possible to add logic to the OnModelBuild event, but I'd rather use the key attributes on the model if possible.

Comment: Looks like you are using one of the key properties (GameId?) in association. What associations to other entities does Game have?

Comment: I'm building a games database that will consist of games from Xbox Live, PSN, and Steam. The Game entity is sort of the super class for each of these network's games. Also, I'll be using the Game entity to represent games not specific to online networks and older consoles such as the SNES or NES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to exclude property Name from the entity key (that I would recommend). Or, use it in all entities if you really need to make it part of the key.

Comment: I need the name of each entity to be unique so it needs to be part of the entity key. I'll try adding Name to all entities. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to not include Name in the entity key. I need to actually check for existence of an entity with the Name before adding a new entity with the same Name. I'll mark my question as answered with your answer.